# How can I load the strut editor in pop-up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, requirejs, impress.js, bespoke.js

I'm using [strut editor](https://github.com/tantaman/Strut) with Rails 4. I want to display the editor in pop-up, but it's loading at the bottom of the page. How can I load "container-fluid" div inside another div?

I'm trying to load the strut editor inside 'popup_body' div, in Ajax response.

```
var content = '';
content +='<div id="results"></div>';
content +='<div id="modals"></div>';
content +='<script data-main="path-to-main.js" src="path-to-require.js"></script>';


$("#popup_body").html(content);
```

Here, strut editor should load inside 'popup_body' div, but, it's loading after 'footer' div, at the bottom.

Comment: What have you done so far? Example of your code attempts might get you more input...

Comment: Edited my question